# Permission Denied in Crontab

Tags: linux, permissions, cron, centos-6

I've searched half a day for the answer to this, with no luck. Any assistance will be appreciated.

I have a PHP script that modifies the crontab, loads a new cron job, removes some etc. The script works fine except that it says permission denied, so it can't write to the crontab.

I've determined that it might be the user trying to access the file that causes permission to be denied. Now I'm not an expert with users and groups (or Linux in general). So could someone please explain to me how I can enable access to the crontab for the linux user 'running' the website?

Comment: Do you want to edit crontab of the user the php script runs under, or crontab of another user? Have you tried editing crontab manually as the user php runs as?

Comment: I want to edit the crontab of the user the php script runs under. I've tried, but it says permission denied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add this line to your `sudoers` file (use `visudo` to edit it):

```
phpuser   ALL = (wwwuser) NOPASSWD: crontab -u wwwuser
```

then your script will be able to run the command

```
sudo -u wwwuser crontab -u wwwuser
```

and pipe in the new contents of the `crontab`.

Comment: As stated, not really experienced with linux so sorry if this question is a bit stupid. Is `phpuser` and `wwwuser` predefined users? The actual account hosting the site running the script is `deltabec`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit.  `phpuser` and `wwwuser` are placeholders for your actual usernames.  So replace `phpuser` with the name of the user running the PHP script, and `wwwuser` with name of the user running the website.

Comment: so in this case both would be `deltabec`?

Comment: It's working now. Thanks a million for the assistance.